# How to place Title and input at same the line in html page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my title and input placed at the same line in the header. But when I add input form after span, the form shows at the new line. Why is it? I thought span and input are inline elements...

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" id="nttLogo">
        <span id="websiteTitle">Online Pharmacy</span>       
        <input type="text" name="searchPattern" placeholder="name" class="form-control">
        <p id="websiteSlogan">Drugs and meds on just about anything</p>
      </div> 
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is when I add bootstrap class *form-control* HTML makes a new line for the input element. How can I have both bootstrap styling and inline displaying for title and input?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You want it like this?

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" id="nttLogo">
        <span id="websiteTitle">Online Pharmacy</span>       
        <input type="text" name="searchPattern" placeholder="name">
        <p id="websiteSlogan" style="display:inline-block">Drugs and meds on just about anything</p>
      </div> 
</div>
```